# Issue using XStream JSON parser, multiple entries in a Map

Tags: java, xstream

I have a class `ReportData`, that has a `Map <Integer, SomeObject>` and elements are `put` to, represented here as `SomeMap`

After running this bean through `xstream` as follows i notice 2 `entry` elements instead of one

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
    xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
    System.out.println(xstream.toXML(rd));
```

This is how JSON should look like

[image]

Instead, i see 2 `entries` in my JSON. One is a part of `SomeMap` and the other one appears as a n equal sibling of `SomeMap`. How can one reproduce this effect?

After trying many things, i am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone else runs into the same issue,

```
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
```

should be replaced with

```
xstream.setMode(XStream.ID_REFERENCES);
```